# How to concatenates css files with .map files in sails?

Tags: sails.js

I am a newbie in Nodejs,

When I try to use grunt in sails with 'sails www --prod' command.

My web's style is broken. Then changed css path,

```
<!--STYLES-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="min/production.min.css">
<!--STYLES END-->
```

to

```
<!--STYLES-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="concat/production.css">
<!--STYLES END-->
```

to find what happened, And in the browser console told an error

```
GET http://localhost:88/concat/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found)
```

Now, I know that bootstrap.css can't find .map file and I didn't know how to fix it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy bootstrap.css.map from bootstrap folder to concat folder